# Calculating General Predictive Accuracy in Clips using rules

Tags: clips

I have to calculate the General Predictive Accuracy with the help of some rules using TP, TN, FP, FN parameters in Clips.

My rule is `x1 <=0.58 AND x6 <=0.61 x5` `mcg<=0.61 --> Class = cp`.
I have written the code but when I try to run it I face the error message. There might be a mistake that I cannot find. 
Can please anyone help me??? 
 This is My Code:

```
(defrule rule1
    (rw6 ?x6)
    (rw5 ?x5)
    (rw1 ?x1)
    (test (<= ?x6 0.58))
    (test (<= ?x5 0.61))
    (test (<= ?x1 0.61))
    ?fact1 <- (TP1 ?TP1)
    ?fact2 <- (FP1 ?FP1)
    ?fact3 <- (TN2 ?TN2)
    ?fact4 <- (TN3 ?TN3)
    ?fact5 <- (TN4 ?TN4)
    ?fact6 <- (FN2 ?FN2)
    ?fact7 <- (FN3 ?FN3)
    ?fact8 <- (FN4 ?FN4)
    ?fact9 <- (K1 ?K1)
    ?fact10 <- (K2 ?K2)
    ?fact11 <- (K3 ?K3)
    ?fact12 <- (K4 ?K4)
    ?fact13 <- (row (rw1 ?x1)(rw2 ?x2)(rw3 ?x3)(rw4 ?x4)(rw5 ?x5)(rw6 ?x6)(rw7 ?x7)(class ?c))
    =>
    (if (= ?c cp) then 
    (retract ?fact1 ?fact3 ?fact4 ?fact5 ?fact9)
    (assert (TP1 (+ ?TP1 1))(TN2 (+ ?TN2 1))(TN3 (+ ?TN3 1))(TN4 (+ ?TN4 1))(K1 (+ ?K1 1))))
    else (if (= ?c im) then 
    (retract ?fact2 ?fact4 ?fact5 ?fact6 ?fact10)
    (assert (FP1 (+ ?FP1 1))(TN3 (+ ?TN3 1))(TN4 (+ ?TN4 1))(FN2 (+ ?FN2 1))(K2 (+ ?K2 1))))
    else (if (= ?c pp) then 
    (retract ?fact2 ?fact3 ?fact5 ?fact7 ?fact11)
    (assert (FP1 (+ ?FP1 1))(TN2 (+ ?TN2 1))(TN4 (+ ?TN4 1))(FN3 (+ ?FN3 1))(K3 (+ ?K3 1))))
    else (if (= ?c om) then
    (retract ?fact2 ?fact3 ?fact4 ?fact8 ?fact12)
    (assert (FP1 (+ ?FP1 1))(TN2 (+ ?TN2 1))(TN3 (+ ?TN3 1))(FN4 (+ ?FN4 1))(K4 (+ ?K4 1))))
    (retract ?fact13))

(defrule rule2
        (K1 ?K1)
    (K2 ?K2)
    (K3 ?K3)
    (K4 ?K4)
    (TP1 ?TP1)
    (FP1 ?FP1)
    (FN1 ?FN1)
    (TP2 ?TP2)
    (FP2 ?FP2)
    (FN2 ?FN2)
    (TP3 ?TP3)
    (FP3 ?FP3)
    (FN3 ?FN3)
    (TP4 ?TP4)
    (FP4 ?FP4)
    (FN4 ?FN4)
    ?fact1 <- (REC1 0)
    ?fact2 <- (REC2 0)
    ?fact3 <- (REC3 0)
    ?fact4 <- (REC4 0)
    ?fact5 <- (PRE1 0)
    ?fact6 <- (PRE2 0)
    ?fact7 <- (PRE3 0)
    ?fact8 <- (PRE4 0)
    ?fact9 <- (FMES1 0)
    ?fact10 <- (FMES2 0)
    ?fact11 <- (FMES3 0)
    ?fact12 <- (FMES4 0)
    ?fact13 <- (waREC 0)
    ?fact14 <- (waPRE 0)
    ?fact15 <- (waFMES 0)
    ?fact13 <- (ACC 0)
    =>
    (retract ?fact1 ?fact2 ?fact3 ?fact4 ?fact5 ?fact6 ?fact7 ?fact8 ?fact9 ?fact10 ?fact11 ?fact12 ?fact13)
    (assert (ACC (bind ?ACC (/ (+ ?TP1 ?TP2 ?TP3 ?TP4)(+ ?TP1 ?TP2 ?TP3 ?TP4 ?FN1 ?FN2 ?FN3 ?FN4)))))
    (assert (REC1 (bind ?REC1 (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FN1)))))
    (assert (REC2 (bind ?REC2 (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FN2)))))
    (assert (REC3 (bind ?REC3 (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FN3)))))
    (assert (REC4 (bind ?REC4 (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FN4)))))
    (assert (PRE1 (bind ?PRE1 (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FP1)))))
    (assert (PRE2 (bind ?PRE2 (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FP2)))))
    (assert (PRE3 (bind ?PRE3 (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FP3)))))
    (assert (PRE4 (bind ?PRE4 (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FP4)))))
    (assert (FMES1 (bind ?FMES1 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FN1))(/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FP1)))(+ (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FN1))(/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FP1)))))))
    (assert (FMES2 (bind ?FMES2 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FN2))(/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FP2)))(+ (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FN2))(/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FP2)))))))
    (assert (FMES3 (bind ?FMES3 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FN3))(/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FP3)))(+ (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FN3))(/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FP3)))))))
    (assert (FMES4 (bind ?FMES4 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FN4))(/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FP4)))(+ (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FN4))(/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FP4)))))))
    (assert (waREC (+ (*(/ ?K1 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC1 )(*(/ ?K2 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC2)(*(/ ?K3 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC3 )(*(/ ?K4 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC4))))
    (assert (waPRE (+ (*(/ ?K1 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?PRE1)(*(/ ?K2 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?PRE2)(*(/ ?K3 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?PRE3)(*(/ ?K4 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC4))))
    (assert (waFMES (+ (*(/ ?K1 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?FMES1)(*(/ ?K2 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?FMES2)(*(/ ?K3 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?FMES3)(*(/ ?K4 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC4)))))
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message that is being displayed?

Comment: The error message that I get is the following:Defining defrule: rule1 
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::rule1
   (rw6 ?x6)
   (rw5 ?x5)
   (rw1 ?x1)
   (test (and (<= ?x6 0.58) (<= ?x5 0.61) (<= ?x1 0.61)))
   ?fact1 <- (TP1 ?TP1)
   ?fact2 <- (FP1 ?FP1)
   ?fact3 <- (TN2 ?TN2)
   ?fact4 <- (TN3 ?TN3)
   ?fact5 <- (TN4 ?TN4)
 FALSE

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues.

You don't have a deftemplate defined for the row fact.

You're using = to compare a variable to a symbol in rule1. Use eq instead if you're comparing non-numeric arguments

In rule2, the fact address ?fact13 is bound to two different patterns.

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate row 
   (slot rw1)
   (slot rw2)
   (slot rw3)
   (slot rw4)
   (slot rw5)
   (slot rw6)
   (slot rw7)
   (slot class))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rule1
    (rw6 ?x6)
    (rw5 ?x5)
    (rw1 ?x1)
    (test (<= ?x6 0.58))
    (test (<= ?x5 0.61))
    (test (<= ?x1 0.61))
    ?fact1 <- (TP1 ?TP1)
    ?fact2 <- (FP1 ?FP1)
    ?fact3 <- (TN2 ?TN2)
    ?fact4 <- (TN3 ?TN3)
    ?fact5 <- (TN4 ?TN4)
    ?fact6 <- (FN2 ?FN2)
    ?fact7 <- (FN3 ?FN3)
    ?fact8 <- (FN4 ?FN4)
    ?fact9 <- (K1 ?K1)
    ?fact10 <- (K2 ?K2)
    ?fact11 <- (K3 ?K3)
    ?fact12 <- (K4 ?K4)
    ?fact13 <- (row (rw1 ?x1)(rw2 ?x2)(rw3 ?x3)(rw4 ?x4)(rw5 ?x5)(rw6 ?x6)(rw7 ?x7)(class ?c))
    =>
    (if (eq ?c cp) ; was =
       then 
       (retract ?fact1 ?fact3 ?fact4 ?fact5 ?fact9)
       (assert (TP1 (+ ?TP1 1))(TN2 (+ ?TN2 1))(TN3 (+ ?TN3 1))(TN4 (+ ?TN4 1))(K1 (+ ?K1 1))))
       else 
       (if (eq ?c im) 
          then 
          (retract ?fact2 ?fact4 ?fact5 ?fact6 ?fact10)
          (assert (FP1 (+ ?FP1 1))(TN3 (+ ?TN3 1))(TN4 (+ ?TN4 1))(FN2 (+ ?FN2 1))(K2 (+ ?K2 1))))
          else 
          (if (eq ?c pp) 
             then 
             (retract ?fact2 ?fact3 ?fact5 ?fact7 ?fact11)
             (assert (FP1 (+ ?FP1 1))(TN2 (+ ?TN2 1))(TN4 (+ ?TN4 1))(FN3 (+ ?FN3 1))(K3 (+ ?K3 1))))
             else (if (eq ?c om) 
             then
             (retract ?fact2 ?fact3 ?fact4 ?fact8 ?fact12)
             (assert (FP1 (+ ?FP1 1))(TN2 (+ ?TN2 1))(TN3 (+ ?TN3 1))(FN4 (+ ?FN4 1))(K4 (+ ?K4 1))))
             (retract ?fact13))
CLIPS> 
(defrule rule2
    (K1 ?K1)
    (K2 ?K2)
    (K3 ?K3)
    (K4 ?K4)
    (TP1 ?TP1)
    (FP1 ?FP1)
    (FN1 ?FN1)
    (TP2 ?TP2)
    (FP2 ?FP2)
    (FN2 ?FN2)
    (TP3 ?TP3)
    (FP3 ?FP3)
    (FN3 ?FN3)
    (TP4 ?TP4)
    (FP4 ?FP4)
    (FN4 ?FN4)
    ?fact1 <- (REC1 0)
    ?fact2 <- (REC2 0)
    ?fact3 <- (REC3 0)
    ?fact4 <- (REC4 0)
    ?fact5 <- (PRE1 0)
    ?fact6 <- (PRE2 0)
    ?fact7 <- (PRE3 0)
    ?fact8 <- (PRE4 0)
    ?fact9 <- (FMES1 0)
    ?fact10 <- (FMES2 0)
    ?fact11 <- (FMES3 0)
    ?fact12 <- (FMES4 0)
    ?fact13 <- (waREC 0)
    ?fact14 <- (waPRE 0)
    ?fact15 <- (waFMES 0)
    ?fact16 <- (ACC 0)
    =>
    (retract ?fact1 ?fact2 ?fact3 ?fact4 ?fact5 ?fact6 ?fact7 ?fact8 ?fact9 ?fact10 ?fact11 ?fact12 ?fact13)
    (assert (ACC (bind ?ACC (/ (+ ?TP1 ?TP2 ?TP3 ?TP4)(+ ?TP1 ?TP2 ?TP3 ?TP4 ?FN1 ?FN2 ?FN3 ?FN4)))))
    (assert (REC1 (bind ?REC1 (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FN1)))))
    (assert (REC2 (bind ?REC2 (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FN2)))))
    (assert (REC3 (bind ?REC3 (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FN3)))))
    (assert (REC4 (bind ?REC4 (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FN4)))))
    (assert (PRE1 (bind ?PRE1 (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FP1)))))
    (assert (PRE2 (bind ?PRE2 (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FP2)))))
    (assert (PRE3 (bind ?PRE3 (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FP3)))))
    (assert (PRE4 (bind ?PRE4 (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FP4)))))
    (assert (FMES1 (bind ?FMES1 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FN1))(/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FP1)))(+ (/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FN1))(/ ?TP1 (+ ?TP1 ?FP1)))))))
    (assert (FMES2 (bind ?FMES2 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FN2))(/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FP2)))(+ (/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FN2))(/ ?TP2 (+ ?TP2 ?FP2)))))))
    (assert (FMES3 (bind ?FMES3 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FN3))(/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FP3)))(+ (/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FN3))(/ ?TP3 (+ ?TP3 ?FP3)))))))
    (assert (FMES4 (bind ?FMES4 (/ (* 2 (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FN4))(/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FP4)))(+ (/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FN4))(/ ?TP4 (+ ?TP4 ?FP4)))))))
    (assert (waREC (+ (*(/ ?K1 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC1 )(*(/ ?K2 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC2)(*(/ ?K3 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC3 )(*(/ ?K4 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC4))))
    (assert (waPRE (+ (*(/ ?K1 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?PRE1)(*(/ ?K2 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?PRE2)(*(/ ?K3 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?PRE3)(*(/ ?K4 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC4))))
    (assert (waFMES (+ (*(/ ?K1 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?FMES1)(*(/ ?K2 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?FMES2)(*(/ ?K3 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?FMES3)(*(/ ?K4 (+ ?K1 ?K2 ?K3 ?K4)) ?REC4)))))
CLIPS>
```